# JQuery convert selector to array of JQuery objects

Tags: jquery

I often need to convert the result of a selector to an array of JQuery objects so that I can `for..of` on them, I end up doing a lot of:

```
const arr = $.makeArray($(selector)).map(el => $(el));
```

(I usually have a function doing this internally)

I then do things like:

```
for (let jel of arr) jel.toggle(false);
```

Does JQuery have a better/builtin way to create such `arr` ?

Comment: [`get`](https://api.jquery.com/get/#get2). There's bound to be a previous question on this, I'll see if I can find one.

Comment: You can use `Array.from(collection)` or `[...collection]` as the generic way to convert an array-like object to a real array. But why do you need to use `for-of` when jQuery has a built-in `$(selector).each(...)`?

Comment: the point is to convert back to a result array where each item is not a dom object but a JQuery object

Comment: @kofifus - Sorry, misunderstood that. I'm curious what the use case is...? Vs. just using `$()` on what you get in the `for-of`?

Comment: the use case is to make the code clear, for more complex case then above one-liner I will need to introduce another `const jel = $(el);` so I can use it in multiple places which I find redundant

Comment: hmm... I'm confused. Why aren't you just using `$(selector).toggle(false)`? feel like i'm missing something, since noone's mentioned this yet. There's rarely ever a need to actually have an array of individual jquery collections. jquery methods already implicitly work on each element individually.

Comment: @KevinB - It's a good point. I have a habit of just assuming there's a reason without questioning it. :-)

Comment: it's, almost an inverse of the way jquery works, you've (we've) created a plugin to allow iterating over a jquery collection and doing something with a for of, rather than creating  a plugin that does the something on each element in the collection. it's backwards, ;)

Comment: @KevinB I often have a lot of operations inside my for..of which cannot be dealt with a single JQuery op

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Kevin points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73667810/jquery-convert-selector-to-array-of-jquery-objects/73667870?noredirect=1#comment130088795_73667810), in that **specific** case, there's no reason for the loop. `toggle` operates on the entire collection, so simply `$("selector").toggle(false)` (or `$("selector").hide();`). This is one of the great things about jQuery, it's *set-based* (for setters and actions; not for getters).

But if the goal is to get an array of individual jQuery wrappers around every element in a jQuery object, your version seems fine, but it can be *slightly* simpler:

```
const arr = Array.from($(selector), el => $(el));
```

That uses the mapping callback on [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), avoiding an unnecessary intermediate array:

```js
const wrappers = Array.from($(".a"), (el) => $(el));
for (const wrapper of wrappers) {
    console.log(wrapper.text());
}
```

```html
<div class="a">1</div>
<div class="a">2</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If the goal is just to get an *iterable* (rather than an array) that can be used with `for-of` and anything else that understands iterables, wrapping each individual element in a jQuery wrapper, you could add a function (plugin) to do that using a [generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*):

```js
// The plugin
(($) => {
    jQuery.fn.wrapped = function*() {
        for (let n = 0; n < this.length; ++n) {
            yield $(this[n]);
        }
    };
})(jQuery);

// Using it
for (const wrapper of $(".a").wrapped()) {
    console.log(wrapper.text());
}
```

```html
<div class="a">1</div>
<div class="a">2</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or as a static method inspired by your comment below:

```js
// The plugin
(($) => {
    $.iterable = function*(...args) {
        const wrapper = $(...args);
        for (let n = 0; n < wrapper.length; ++n) {
            yield $(wrapper[n]);
        }
    };
})(jQuery);

// Using it
for (const wrapper of $.iterable(".a")) {
    console.log(wrapper.text());
}
```

```html
<div class="a">1</div>
<div class="a">2</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: oh cool I didn't know `Array.from` can do this ! glad I asked

Comment: instead of you plugin I added: `JQuery.from = function (selector) { return Array.from($(selector), el => $(el)); }` I can then `for .. of $.from('.class')`